# How to add, retrieve and update fields which are not implemented in models using djongo?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

I am using mongoDB as my primary database in a django project. I am using djongo engine for accessing and manipulating mongoDB. For testing I wrote a simple student  model

```
class StudentModel(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = model.IntegerField()
```

and insereted data to this model using

```
from app.models import StudentModel
StudentModel(name="John" age=10).save()
```

Because mongoDB is schemaless database I want to try and add fields which are not implemented in StudentModel, I have tried to insert a new student with additional email address field.

```
StudentModel(name="Steve" age=9, email="steve@email.com").save()
```

But it gives this type error

> TypeError: StudentModel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'

This is my database setup in `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'djongo',
           'NAME': 'testdb',
           'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': 'False',
       }
}
```

How do we add, retrieve and update fields which are not implemented in models using djongo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw_query as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can add email field to your model as null=True, then if you add email when you are creating new student it will save with email otherwhise email section will be null.